# how to match img tag - negate lookahead

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to match an `img` tag with a negate lookahead?

```
/(<img (?!.*\/>).*\/>)/i
```

Comment: Sorry, could you be little more clear? Maybe some sample input and expected output?

Comment: You don't require a lookahead, `/<img[^>]*?>/i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need lookahead here, can't you do:

```
/(<img\s[^>]+>)/i
```

However allow me to **strongly** suggest you to use [DOM Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of RegEx here because using RegEx can be error prone for `image` tag like this:

```
<img src="greater.jpg" alt="x > y" height="10" width="10">
```

Comment: Your example of Regex being error-prone is an error in itself, as shown by the colour coding. `>` must be escaped as `&gt;` in an attribute value. So, providing the HTML writer has a clue what they're doing, Regex is just fine here.

Comment: Agreed, example is probably not syntactically correct HTML but sometimes HTML is indeed poorly written and can give unexpected results while using a RegEx to parse.

Answer (score 1):

That would be:

```
/(<img(?:.(?!\/>))+\/>/i
```

But this is not the most efficient solution there is. Using a lookahead, the most efficient is this:

```
/(<img[^>]+(?:\/(?!>)[^>]*)*\/>)/i
```

Decomposing it, this gives:

```
(              # begin capture
    <img       # literal "<img", followed by
    [^>]+      # everything but ">", once or more, followed by
    (?:        # begin non capturing group
      /(?!>)   # a "/", as long as it is not followed by a ">", followed by
      [^>]*    # everything but ">", zero or more times,
    )*         # zero or more times, followed by
    />         # literal "/>"
)              # end capture
```

This is another application of `normal* (special normal*)*`, with `normal` being `[^>]` and `special` being `/(?!>)`:

```
$ perl -ne 'm,(<img[^>]+(?:/(?!>)[^>]*)*/>), and print "-->$1<--\n"' <<EOF
no image tag here
Here there is one: <img src="foo/bar.gif"/>
<img whatever bla bla> (no match, no / before >)
EOF

--><img src="foo/bar.gif"/><--
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ungreedy [pattern modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) *U*.

> **U (PCRE_UNGREEDY)**
>
> This modifier inverts the "greediness" of the quantifiers so that they are not greedy by default, but become greedy if followed by *?*. It is not compatible with Perl. It can also be set by a (*?U*) [modifier setting within the pattern](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.internal-options.php) or by a question mark behind a quantifier (e.g. *.*?*).

This will grab everything until it encounters `/>` (the end of the `img` tag).

```
'/(<img(.*)/>)/Ui'
```